# C# difference between ref and complex object as parameter

Tags: c#, pointers, parameters, ref, out

I'm curious what happens if I do not use the `ref` declaration for a parameter, instead pass the object it self and manipulate it within the function.

E.g:

```
public void DoStuff(DataPackage context) 
{
    context.IsAValue = false;
}

var context = new DataPackage();
DoStuff(context);

Assert.False(context.IsAValue)
```

And here the other variation:

```
public void DoStuff(ref DataPackage context) 
{
    context.IsAValue = false;
}

var context = new DataPackage();
DoStuff(ref context);

Assert.False(context.IsAValue)
```

I think sometimes in complex scenarios, the pass without the ref does not work like assumed here. Is that true? I´m facing an issue which lets me think that way.

Hope for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example `var context = new DataPackage();` will be ignored and this is intended behavior.

In both examples `context.IsAValue` is false unless its initialized as true

Your second example is an incorrect usage of `ref`

example as per the [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

> Don't confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference.

```
void Method(ref int refArgument)
{
    refArgument = refArgument + 44;
}

int number = 1;
Method(ref number);
Console.WriteLine(number);
// Output: 45
```

Also look at: [passing an argument by reference an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference-an-example)

The ref keyword indicates that a value is passed by reference. It is used in four different contexts:

1. In a method signature and in a method call, to pass an argument to a method by reference. For more information, see Passing an argument by reference.
2. In a method signature, to return a value to the caller by reference. For more information, see Reference return values.
3. **In a member body, to indicate that a reference return value is stored locally as a reference that the caller intends to modify. Or to indicate that a local variable accesses another value by reference. For more information, see Ref locals.**
4. In a struct declaration, to declare a ref struct or a readonly ref struct. For more information, see the ref struct section of the Structure types article.